# Generar muestras aleatorias en R

Tags: r

Estoy realizando un ejercicio, el cual dice lo siguiente:

> Generar 100 muestras de tamaño 200 de una variable aleatoria B(20;
> 0.2).

Para generar muestras aleatorias, conozco y he utilizado la función `sample`. La he utilizado de la siguiente forma:

```
print(sample(1:200, size=100))
```

Simplemente me imprime 100 números aleatorios de entre 1 y 200. Pero no entiendo como hacerlo sobre una variable aleatoria.

**¿Hay alguna otra función que me permita hacer lo que pide el enunciado?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Consideraciones

En este caso por lo que entiendo la variable aleatoria X es una binomial:

> X ~ B(20, 0.2)

R permite generar variables aleatorias (v.a.) de forma sencilla a través de su biblioteca nativa:

**rbinom(n, size, prob)**

**n:** número de observaciones (200),
**size:** es el número de ensayos o muestras (100) y
**prob:** es la probabilidad de éxito en cada ensayo o muestra (0.2)

### Respuesta

Quedando finalmente así:

> rbinom(200,100,0.2)

Un posible resultado:

```
  [1] 18 17 18 21 17 18 20 18 16 22 15 17 25 14 25 23 24 24 19 20 24 24 19 20 20 25 21 19 20 25
 [31] 18 16 26 27 17 17 16 20 18 29 16 17 27 15 22 19 26 27 28 20 21 18 23 15 25 17 23 11 22 25
 [61] 24 18 22 20 22 23 19 19 21 20 18 20 16 18 20 17 23 24 19 18 14 18 23 23 23 25 23 15 20 20
 [91] 19 16 16 26 23 19 24 29 19 21 25 24 20 28 26 22 18 17 16 21 19 20 20 16 20 18 19 18 24 24
[121] 24 17 22 18 24 20 21 24 22 17 22 21 20 18 17 25 27 19 19 23 21 21 19 10 23 16 16 18 21 18
[151] 21  9 19 12 25 27 20 20 19 22 20 22 22 14 26 21 21 30 21 18 22 24 18 20 18 24 23 21 20 14
[181] 16 22 19 28 15 28 17 18 19 22 20 19 19 19 20 18 21 17 20 21
```

### Adicional

Si se observa se obtiene v.a. binomiales muy similares. Una forma de visualizar y comprender mejor este comportamiento es mediante una gráfica

```
x <- seq(0,200,by = 1) 
y <- dbinom(x,200,0.2) 
plot(x,y)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para más detalle se puede consultar en R Studio

```
help("rbinom")
```